# how send command parameter to php file

Tags: php, ubuntu

> Solved : http://php.net/manual/en/function.shell-exec.php

I have a .PHP [file](https://github.com/dukei/hd-wallet-derive/blob/master/hd-wallet-derive.php) that when I run it in terminal ([image](https://ibb.co/8cNBttW)), it's gives outputs and work fine,
for example `sudo ./hd-wallet-derive.php -g`

It is work good in Ubuntu terminal.

So how can I use it in my website?

For example write what to call `sudo ./hd-wallet-derive.php -g` in a php file?

How to pass parameters in php to this file such as in terminal?

I want to use this file's option in my website

Comment: use shell_exec() function to execute the command line commands from PHP.

Comment: Remember sudo is dangerous if exposed to the user, so be extra careful